# SoundCloud API iOS, no sharing - only listening

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, soundcloud

I got a website where I make playlists with SoundCloud. Now I want to make an app for iPhone so the users can listen to the songs there as well.

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart
In the example in the link the users have to sign in to listen and share, but I want my users only to listen. Is there a way around so they don't have to sign in?

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out as well. If I find anything, I'll make sure to come back.

Answer (score 1):

Create a page that outputs the playlist in JSON, then in xcode create a class that downloads the JSON for the track dictionaries and play the downloaded content using AVPlayer (or AVQueuePlayer if you're playing the whole list).

Here's some abstract code:

```
playlistDownloader.m
- (void)downloadPlaylist{
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourwebsite.com/playlist.json?id=1"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;

    id trackData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    if (!error) {
        tempTrackArray = trackData;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Playlist wasn't able to download");
    }
});
}
```

tempTrackArray would be a property declared in the class.

Then in your player, you'd do something like this:

```
audioPlayer.m
- (void)instanciateAudioPlayer
{
NSDictionary *trackDictionary = [playListDownloader.tempTrackArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *urlString = [trackDictionary objectForKey:@"stream_url"];

AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:streamURL];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

[avPlayer initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
}
```

This is some really rough code but its the general gist of what you're trying to do.  Should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: You can't use the stream_url without an authentication header.

Answer (score 1):

Trying the soundcloud quickstart I realised that your stream url needs to begin with https rather than http. Also you need to add your client id from your sound cloud app to the stream url:

```
NSDictionary *trackDictionary = [playListDownloader.tempTrackArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *streamURL = [trackDictionary objectForKey:@"stream_url"]; 
streamURL = [streamURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http" withString:@"https"];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?client_id=%@", streamURL, @"a8e117d3fa2121067e0b29105b0543ef"];
```

From there you just setup the AVPlayer:

```
self._avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[self setupLayer:clayer];
[self._avPlayer play];
```

Everything should work fine. Hope it helps